# How do I get the Rails test database to rebuild before each test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

I'm currently in the process of beginning a migration from fixtures to factories and running into some test database challenges.

When I run my entire test suite the database is cleaned out and the new factory-generated data reloaded.  However, when I run individual unit tests the database does not clean out the old values.

I could run rake db:test:prepare before each individual test, but that would slow down my development.

Here are my test settings:

```
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  self.use_instantiated_fixtures  = true
```

For instance:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'
class LocationTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "should require name to save" do
    location = Factory.create(:location)
  end
end
```

will run once successfully but fail on subsequent runs of the test file.  This never happened previously because the test fixtures would load on each run.

I have added factory sequencing, but that only sequences attributes during each run:

```
  Factory.define :location do |l|
    l.sequence(:name) {|n| "place#{n}"}
    l.street  '123 N Pitt Street'
    l.state_id 4
    l.city 'San Francisco'
    l.location_type_id LocationType::COMMON
    l.shipper_id 1
    l.zip 23658
  end
```

results in:

```
trunk>ruby test\unit\location_test.rb
Loaded suite test/unit/location_test
Started
.
Finished in 0.162 seconds.

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors

>ruby test\unit\location_test.rb
Loaded suite test/unit/location_test
Started
E
Finished in 0.134 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_should_require_name_to_save(LocationTest):
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name has already been taken
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thoughtbot-factory_girl-1.2.1/lib/factory_girl/proxy/create.rb:5:in `result'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thoughtbot-factory_girl-1.2.1/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:293:in `run'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thoughtbot-factory_girl-1.2.1/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:237:in `create'
    test/unit/location_test.rb:18:in `test_should_require_name_to_save'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your test settings to make certain that they are what you want, although I suspect you may have a reason to disallow the standard practice of running a test in a transaction (which is rolled back upon exit).

The other options is 
  (1) Manually use transactions for tests like the one above (where there is not already a transaction), plus
  (2) Add a `teardown` method to manually clean out the relevant tables.

Comment: Add:

self.use_transactional_fixtures = true

to this class and it works!  Thank you.

Yes, there are reasons why I cannot change it for the whole environment.  I didn't even think to change it for just this one test...doh!

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `setup` method in your unit test so that it deletes the data you want cleaned out.

Answer (score 0):

Since every test *should* start from a clean database, try to get things in your codebase to the point where you *can* use transactions for each test. Your test quality will be much improved as a result.

Also, this is not directly related to your question...but never use Rails fixtures, under any circumstances, for anything. Use factories instead (check out the factory_girl_rails gem). Also, check out RSpec instead of Test::Unit.